# Async Web API and Ajax

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a long running job that is started from the admins web page.
The Job can only be started once, and therefore I have a singleton, that also holds the different state messages of the job.

After the admin has started the job (Ajax call works)  a timer in javascript gets started, that should trigger checks of the state of the job every 10 seconds (the timer works, the calls get triggered).
My Problem is, that these calls never reach the server, until the Job is finished ... After the job has finished, all the status calls (that should have been async) are processed..

WEB API CODE:

```
public class CleanUpServiceToolController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task StartJob(StartCondition startCondition)
    {

        if (CleanUpServiceTool.Instance.Status == "Neu")
        {
            CleanUpServiceTool.Instance.Status = "I'm Busy";
            await Task.Delay(60*1000);//CleanUpServiceTool.Instance.Start(startCondition);
            CleanUpServiceTool.Instance.Status = "Neu";
        }
    }

    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return CleanUpServiceTool.Instance.Status;;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT  the javascripts are logically splitted.. but all calls go through this code

```
return $.ajax({
    url:  url
    type: type,
    data: (type === "PUT" || type === "POST") ? JSON.stringify(input) : input,
    contentType: contentType,
    dataType: dataType,
    jsonpCallback: jsonpCallbackFunctionName,
    timeout: timeout,
    async: true,
    cache: false
}).done(function (response) {
    var output = dataType === "jsonp" ? response : JSON.parse(response, true);
    successCallback(output);
}).fail(function (response) {
    var output;
    try {
        output = JSON.parse(response.responseText, false);
    } catch (exception) {
        output = response.responseText;
    }
    errorCallback(response.status, response.statusText, output);
}).always(function () {
    if (alwaysCallback) {
        alwaysCallback();
    }
});
```

My code makes something like this:

1. get status of the job/ instance (Works)
2. if status is "Neu" then enable the "Start Job" Button (works)
3. on click send ajax POST data to the server  (works, server starts the Job)
4. Start a timer and Ask for job status  **(Does NOT work: The calls get stacked  and only get called when the StartJob Task is finished...**

To test the javascript logic I used Task.Delay, I don't want to start up the job each time during testing.

I really don't know why my "async" calls are actualy "sync" calls!

I even tried making the GetStatus async , which really doesn't make much sence, (opening a thread just to read the Property of my instance)

Any Ideas, suggestions, fixes?
Thanks

Comment: async/sync has nothing to do with the serialization you're seeing. The most common cause of serialization on ASP.NET is due to the session (see [Concurrent Requests and Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)). It's not normal to enable session state on WebAPIs, but some people do.

Comment: Sorry... what serialization are you talking about?. I just want to make 2 ajax calls. And want to get response from the api... not waiting for one to finish

Comment: Ohh... now I'm in trouble it seems that  my Cms does use sessions.... so... any ideas how to solve that problem with the session?